# Editing in a repeater one row at a time

Tags: asp.net

I have an written the code for an editable repeater, now the problem i am facing is that i can edit multiple rows in a repeater at a single time.The functionality which i want to implement is that if click on edit one row, and at the same time click edit on another row it should some prompt to me to save the first row.

Comment: You can declare a javascript variable set its value to false if any row goes to edit mode assign true, on edit complete assign false, check this variable before editing the row if this variable is true show the message to user to save the first row before editing this row.

Comment: I got the solution what i did was i put a incremented variable in view state whenever my row was edited,next time i had already stored incremented variable in it so if it was >1 then i gave a script message to save or cancel the editted row.